# Efficiently map any string to a unique number that represents the dictionary order of the string

Tags: java, string, sorting, hash, clojure

I would like to convert any unicode string to a unique number (in Clojure or Java). I want the generated number to have the following properties:
- It is unique for that string
- When a set of such numbers are sorted and mapped back to the original strings, the strings will appear in sorted order. The strings are not all known in advance.

One way this could be done is:

```
(defn strval [^String s]
    (bigdec (reduce #(str %1 (format "%05d" (int %2))) "0." s)))
```

We can validate the sort order is correct with:

```
(assert (< (strval "a") (strval "b")))
(assert (< (strval "a") (strval "aa")))
(assert (< (strval "aa") (strval "ab")))
```

(Ignore, if you like that “int” is not necessarily the best way to get the sort order of an individual character.)

For those not familiar with Clojure, this algorithm:

1. Converts the string into a sequence of characters
2. Gets the integer value of one character
3. Converts this integer to a string and pads it with zeros so that it makes a string of five characters.
4. Appends this string to a result string that starts with “0.”
5. If there are more characters go back to step 2, otherwise
6. Converts the result string to a Java BigDecimal

However, the process of creating a BigDecimal in this way is sub-optimal:

1. It relies on converting between numbers and strings and then back to a the final number.
2. Padding each value with zeros does not produce the most compact representation.

What alternatives are there to the function that will speed it up and make the generated number smaller if possible, while retaining the uniqueness and sorting properties described above?

Note: The solution does not have produce a BigDecimal, it just has to produce a number, but I don't know how you could make this work with a BigInteger. Also, I realise the function can be memoized to speed subsequent executions but I’m after a performance increase in the initial execution.

Comment: The smallest most efficient mapping function for uniquely mapping strings to ints is a well known/studied problem. There are various mapping schemes with names like ASCII and UTF8/16.

Answer (score 8):

Not possible in general, but possible if your entire universe of strings is known in advance.  What you are asking for is a hash function that preserves lexicographic sort order.  In order to do that, the hash function has to produce a unique value for every possible string -- i.e. a hash function with no collisions over all possible inputs.  The length of the hash value in this case has a lower bound equal to the number of bits of information in the input.

To see why this is impossible in general, consider a collection of random strings of length, say, 1000 consisting of only `[A-Za-z0-9]`.  There are 62 possible values for each letter, call it 6 bits of data (rounded up slightly).  Thus the number of possible distinct values is approximately 62<sup>1000</sup>, or about 10<sup>1792</sup>.  How to you plan to encode those values in your hash function?  Preserving order such that you could correctly sort `"[999 random characters]A"` and `"[same 999 random characters]B"` would require a hash code at least 6000 bits long.

If you know in advance all the possible strings you can sort the list and assign hash values in increasing order, but that probably is not what you want.

Also, if the maximum length of the strings is bounded (i.e. all strings are less than some reasonable value) you *might* be able to come up with an encoding that works.  You'd need to figure out the total number of bits required to encode all possible values, which would be

> ceil(log<sub>2</sub>(`A`<sup>`L`</sup>))

where `L` is the maximum length of string, and `A` is the size of the alphabet, i.e. the number of distinct characters that can occur in each position of a maximal-length string.  So, for example, for a max length of 10 and an alphabet consisting of `[A-Z]`, the number of bits required would be the base-2 logarithm of 26<sup>10</sup> which, rounded up, is 48.

Designing an order-preserving hash that fits in the optimal 48 bits would probably be pretty difficult. A slightly less optimal approach is to calculate the number of bits required for each symbol, which is

> ceil(log<sub>2</sub>(A))

which in your case is 5 bits.  Encode each 8-bit byte down to 5 bits, pack those bits into a binary string and write it out as a byte stream.

Comment: Unfortunately, the strings are not known in advance so I can't use perfect hashing. I could perhaps impose a maximum bound for size but I'd rather not. Typical sizes will be short (3-10 characters) and generally will be standard latin text but should work for any length and any unicode character. I've used BigDecimal fractions for my current encoding because they maps exactly to the string, are unbounded and, most importantly, preserve the sort order property. I don't see any easy way of getting away from that BigDecimal because of those constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This application is covered in the JDK by the class [`java.text.CollationKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/CollationKey.html). `CollationKey` is a representation of some string’s (Unicode) collation order.

So, if you’re on the Java platform, you can easily obtain collation keys and compare them directly – that’s what they’re made for:

```clj
(def root-collator (java.text.Collator/getInstance java.util.Locale/ROOT))

(defn collation-key [s]
  (.getCollationKey root-collator s))

(compare (collation-key "a") (collation-key "b"))  ; => -1
```

`CollationKey` has a [`toByteArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/CollationKey.html#toByteArray--) method that returns an array of bytes representing the key. Since these byte arrays are directly comparable with one another, you can pour their contents into big integers if you must:

```clj
(defn bigint-key [s]
  (-> s collation-key .toByteArray bigint))

;; these all pass:
(assert (< (bigint-key "a") (bigint-key "b")))
(assert (< (bigint-key "a") (bigint-key "aa")))
(assert (< (bigint-key "aa") (bigint-key "ab")))
```

(I’m not 100% sure `bigint-key` is correct. A collation key byte array is unsigned, but a `java.math.BigInteger` byte array is a two’s complement representation; some legwork to deal with signedness may be necessary.)

You stress that you have some constraints on space/performance, so I’m not sure this solution is at all helpful. Still, it’s good to be aware that a thing such as `CollationKey` exists in the JDK and can be applied to this problem with a minimal amount of code.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't help a lot with my main question which is more around efficient encoding but is still good to know as I was simply using the integer representation of the unicode character as measure of closeness which isn't great. I didn't know about Collators and this will definitely help with that - so not what I was after in this question but useful anyway :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how Clojure or Java handle Interfacing to C, but that sounds like the C standard library’s strxfrm function.  That said, strxfrm’s results only work if both strings are transformed with the same LC_COLLATE setting.  In other words, it wouldn’t make sense to compare a German word to a French word, since these languages have different rules about how to sort words.

If you can use collation with byte string comparison (which covers all the times I’ve needed something like this), then strxfrm is all you need.  But if you really need numeric comparison, then you have to do more.

If you do need numeric comparison, then you have to involve arbitrary precision integers (like Java’s BigInteger; you don’t need BigDecimal).  After all, you can’t compare two seven-character strings as 64-bit integers (by the pigeonhole principle).

In that case, your best bet is to interpret the resulting byte string as an arbitrary-precision big-endian number.  In other words, if the length of the byte string is seven bytes, you’ll need to build a resulting number as `(byte_string[0]<<64) + (byte_string[1]<<56) + … + (byte_string[6]<<0)` (where each byte is left-shifted by the total length minus its position * 8 bits).

I haven’t actually come across a situation where it’s useful to transform a string into an arbitrary-precision number in a manner that preserves collation, like you’re trying to do here.  Usually, I find that I need to transform a Unicode string into a bytestring that preserves collation order under a memcmp-like comparison.  However, certainly there may be some database layers that require what you’re asking for (presumably using something like Elias gamma coding under the hood for arbitrary-precision numbers).  If that’s what you’ve got, then using strxfrm followed by an arbitrary-precision big-endian interpretation (as I’ve described here) may be what you need.